# Functional way to map over a list with an accumulator in Scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I would like to write succinct code to map over a list, accumulating a value as I go and using that value in the output list.

Using a recursive function and pattern matching this is straightforward (see below). But I was wondering if there is a way to do this using the function programming family of combinators like map and fold etc. Obviously map and fold are no good unless you use a mutable variable defined outside the call and modify that in the body.

Perhaps I could do this with a State Monad but was wondering if there is a way to do it that I'm missing, and that utilizes the Scala standard library.

```
// accumulate(List(10, 20, 20, 30, 20))
// => List(10, 30, 50, 80, 100,)

def accumulate(weights : List[Int], sum : Int = 0, acc: List[Int] = List.empty) : List[Int] = {
  weights match {
    case hd :: tl =>
      val total = hd + sum
      accumulate(tl, total, total :: acc)
    case Nil =>
      acc.reverse
  }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This could be done with scan:

```
val result = list.scanLeft(0){case (acc, item) => acc+item}
```

Scan will include the initial value 0 into output so you have to drop it:

```
result.drop(1)
```

Answer (score 10):

You may also use `foldLeft`:

```
def accumulate(seq: Seq[Int]) =
  seq.foldLeft(Vector.empty[Int]) { (result, e) =>
    result :+ result.lastOption.getOrElse(0) + e
  }

accumulate(List(10, 20, 20, 30, 20))
// => List(10, 30, 50, 80, 100,)
```

Answer (score 4):

As pointed out in [@Nyavro's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47007773/2988), the operation you are looking for (the sum of the prefixes of the list) is called [*prefix-sum*](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Prefix_sum) and its generalization to any binary operation is called [`scan`](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Prefix_sum#Scan_higher_order_function) and is [included in the Scala standard library](http://scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/GenTraversableLike.html#scan[B>:A,That](z:B)(op:(B,B)=>B)(implicitcbf:scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom[Repr,B,That]):That):

```
val l = List(10, 20, 20, 30, 20)

l.scan(0) { _ + _ }
//=> List(0, 10, 30, 50, 80, 100)

l.scan(0)(_ + _).drop(1)
//=> List(10, 30, 50, 80, 100)
```

This has already been answered, but I wanted to address a misconception in your question:

> Obviously map and fold are no good unless you use a mutable variable defined outside the call and modify that in the body.

That is not true. `fold` is a *general* method of iteration. *Everything* you can do by iterating over a collection, you can do with `fold`. If `fold` were the *only* method in your `List` class, you could still do everything you can do now. Here's how to solve your problem with [`fold`](http://scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/GenTraversableOnce.html#fold[A1>:A](z:A1)(op:(A1,A1)=>A1):A1):

```
l.foldLeft(List(0)) { (list, el) ⇒ list.head + el :: list }.reverse.drop(1)
```

And a general implementation of `scan`:

```
def scan[A](l: List[A])(z: A)(op: (A, A) ⇒ A) = 
  l.
    drop(1).
    foldLeft(List(l.head)) { (list, el) ⇒ op(list.head, el) :: list }.
    reverse
```

Think of it this way: a collection can be either empty or not. `fold` has two arguments, one which tells it what to do when the list is empty, and one which tells it what to do when the list is not empty. Those are the only two cases, so every possible case is handled. Therefore, `fold` can do anything! (More precisely in Scala, `foldLeft` and `foldRight` can do anything, while `fold` is restricted to associative operations.)

Or a different viewpoint: a collection is a stream of instructions, either the `EMPTY` instruction or the `ELEMENT(value)` instruction. `foldLeft` / `foldRight` are skeleton *interpreters* for that instruction set, and you as a programmer can supply the implementation for the interpretation of both those instructions, namely the two arguments to `foldLeft` / `foldRight` *are* the interpretation of those instructions.

Remember: while `foldLeft` / `foldRight` reduces a collection to a single value, that value can be arbitrarily complex, including being a collection itself!

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I was struggling to see how to use scan and fold but the missing piece for me was having List(0) as the zero value. After that everything made sense.

Comment: The general way to solve the problem is to use a tuple `(theRealAccumulator, tempVar1, tempVar2, tempVar3, …)` as the accumulator and then select `result._1` afterwards. In this case, it just so happens that the `head` of the accumulator is also the temporary value we want to keep. But, for example, if you wanted to implement `zipWithIndex` using `foldLeft`, you would need to keep a tuple of `(resultList, i)` as the accumulator.